# Split datetime into months SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table that looks like this :

```
Name |     DateFrom     |      DateTo
 A   | 2017-01-04 10:50 | 2017-03-05 18:20
 B   | 2017-01-31 23:00 | 2017-02-03 10:00
```

and i would like to split each date into one row per month like this :

```
Name |     DateFrom     |      DateTo
 A   | 2017-01-04 10:50 | 2017-02-01 00:00
 A   | 2017-02-01 00:00 | 2017-03-01 00:00
 A   | 2017-03-01 00:00 | 2017-03-05 18:20
 B   | 2017-01-31 23:00 | 2017-02-01 00:00  
 B   | 2017-02-01 00:00 | 2017-02-03 10:00
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: create a function which return month wise startdate for given start and end date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Uzi doesn't return the expected value. I took his script and changed.

```
with cte (Name, DateFrom, DateTo) as (
    select 
        a, cast(b as datetime), cast(c as datetime) 
    from (values 
          ('A', '20170104 10:50', '20170305 18:20')
         ,('B', '20170131 23:00', '20170203 10:00')
         ,('C', '20170130 23:00', '20170131 10:00')
         ,('D', '20170331 23:00', '20170330 10:00')
    ) t (a, b, c)
)
, rcte as (
    select 
        Name, DateFrom, (CASE WHEN Cast(EOMONTH(DateFrom, 0) as Date) >= Cast(DateTo as date) THEN DateTo ELSE DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(DateFrom, 0)) END) DateTo, DateFrom OriginalDateFrom, DateTo OriginalDateTo, 1 step       
    from cte
    union all
    select 
        Name, rcte.DateTo, (CASE WHEN Cast(EOMONTH(rcte.DateTo, 0) as Date) >= Cast(rcte.OriginalDateTo as Date) THEN rcte.OriginalDateTo ELSE DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(rcte.DateTo, 0)) END), rcte.OriginalDateFrom, rcte.OriginalDateTo, rcte.step + 1    
    from rcte
    where 
        Cast(EOMONTH(DateFrom, 0) as Date) < Cast(rcte.OriginalDateTo as Date)          
)
select 
    Name, DateFrom, DateTo, Step
from 
    rcte
ORDER BY Name, DateFrom
```

Comment: Hehe. Nice. But you have added some extra calculations. My mistake was that query was returning 1 month less than needed in `DateTo` column. So you should just add 1 month to that computed column and do not touch recursion :) Updated my query

Comment: @Uzi: If you compare the two execution plans and io statistics, you will see that your query is more complex. Your "max(step) over (partition by Name)" is expensive and requires an additional scan. Also, my version (except oemonth) is compatible with any version of SQLS. Finally, I stylistically prefer to have a final select cleaner than the CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Use `recursive CTE` to achieve that

```
with cte (Name, DateFrom, DateTo) as (
    select 
        a, cast(b as datetime), cast(c as datetime) 
    from (values 
        ('A', '20170104 10:50', '20170305 18:20')
         ,('B', '20170131 23:00', '20170203 10:00')
    ) t (a, b, c)
)
, rcte as (
    select 
        Name, res = cast(dateadd(dd, 1, eomonth(DateFrom, -1)) as datetime), DateFrom, DateTo, 1 step       
    from cte
    union all
    select
        name, dateadd(mm, 1, res), DateFrom, DateTo, step + 1
    from
        rcte
    where
        dateadd(mm, 1, res) < DateTo

)

select
    name, iif(step = 1, DateFrom, res)
    , iif(step = max(step) over (partition by Name), DateTo, dateadd(mm, 1, res))
from 
    rcte
```

I have used `eomonth` and `iif` which are available from SQL 2012, but they can be easily replaced in older versions

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below query and let me know if I miss something.

```
DECLARE @tblDates AS Table
(
    Name VARCHAR(10),
    DateFrom Datetime,
    DateTo Datetime
)

INSERT INTO @tblDates VALUES('A','2017-01-04 10:50','2017-03-05 18:20')
INSERT INTO @tblDates VALUES('B','2017-01-31 23:00','2017-02-03 10:00')

SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) AS RowNo
INTO #tblDates
FROM @tblDates  

DECLARE @startdate Datetime
DECLARE @enddate Datetime
DECLARE @rowIndex INT=1, @totalCount INT,@Name VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @totalCount=COUNT(*) FROM #tblDates

DECLARE @tempDate Datetime

DECLARE @finalDates AS TABLE(
    Name VARCHAR(10),
    DateFrom Datetime,
    DateTo Datetime
)

WHILE @rowIndex<=@totalCount
BEGIN
    SELECT @Name=Name,@startdate=DateFrom,@tempDate=DateFrom,@enddate=DateTo FROM #tblDates WHERE RowNo=@rowIndex
    ---SELECT 1,@tempDate
    WHILE @tempDate<=@enddate
    BEGIN       
        SET @startdate=DATEADD(m,1,@tempDate)
        ---SELECT @tempDate,@startdate,@enddate
        INSERT INTO @finalDates VALUES(@Name,@tempDate,
            CASE WHEN @startdate>@enddate 
            THEN CASE WHEN MONTH(@endDate)=MONTH(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @startdate), 0)) THEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @enddate), 0) ELSE @enddate END
            ELSE DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @startdate), 0) END)
        SET @tempDate=DATEADD(m,1,@tempDate)
        SET @tempDate=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @tempDate), 0)
    END
    SET @rowIndex=@rowIndex+1
END

SELECT * FROM @finalDates

DROP TABLE #tblDates
```

Comment: Your answer works well too, but i decided to take ildanny's one... Since it's the first one i tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Create Table Calender (one time work)
--create using any logic
create table tblCalender
(
 DATEVal datetime not null primary key
)

insert into tblCalender
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), '19000101')
FROM master..spt_values;

-- your table with millions of data
create table  #t (Name varchar(50),DateFrom datetime, DateTo datetime)
insert into #t VALUES
 ('A','2017-01-04 10:50','2017-03-05 18:20')
 ,('B','2017-01-31 23:00','2017-02-03 10:00')

 create nonclustered index #tFromTo on #t(DateFrom,DateTo)include(name)

 --if you use below 2012 then use  convert(varchar(6), getdate(),112)

SELECT h.NAME
    ,CASE 
        WHEN format(tc.DATEVal, 'yyyyMM') = format(DateFrom, 'yyyyMM')
            THEN DateFrom
        ELSE DATEVal
        END DateFrom
    ,CASE 
        WHEN format(tc.DATEVal, 'yyyyMM') = format(DateTo, 'yyyyMM')
            THEN DateTo
        ELSE dateadd(month, 1, DATEVal)
        END DateTo
FROM #t h
INNER JOIN tblCalender tc ON tc.DATEVal > DATEADD(MONTH, - 1, h.DateFrom)
    AND tc.DATEVal < h.DateTo


    drop table #t
```